# Editar DATATABLE de JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, datatables

Tengo un `DataTable` llenado con una consulta, el problema es que en la base de datos no tengo tantos ceros como me muestra en el `DataTable`

¿Cómo puedo quitarlos?

Además de esto cómo puedo editar algunas características del `DataTable`. Los resultados se muestran de la siguiente manera:
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta es simple, el código esta a continuación:

```
    <?php 

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    require 'vistas/catalogo.view.php';
}else{
    header('location:servicios.php');
}
    //if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        try {
            $servidor='(LOCAL)';
            $base='dbsav300';
            $usuario='XXX';
            $password='XXXXX';

            $conexion=new PDO ("sqlsrv:server=$servidor;Database=$base", "$usuario", "$password");
            echo "Conexion establecida";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error en la conexion:" .$e->getMessage(). "\n";
            exit;
        }

        $consulta=$conexion->prepare('SELECT art_Clave, art_Nombre, art_Total, art_Existencia FROM tArticulo');
        $consulta->execute();

        echo "<table id='table_id' class='display'>";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>SKU</th>";
        echo "<th>NOMBRE</th>";
        echo "<th>PRECIO DE VENTA</th>";
        echo "<th>EXISTENCIA</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";

        echo "<tbody>";
        while ($row=$consulta->fetch()) {
            //print_r($row);
            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<th>'.$row['art_Clave'].'</th>';
            echo '<th>'.$row['art_Nombre'].'</th>';
            echo '<th>'.$row['art_Total'].'</th>';
            echo '<th>'.$row['art_Existencia'].'</th>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";


 ?>
```

Y la función la llamo así:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#table_id').DataTable();
        } );
    </script>
```

Lo curioso que en otra parte de la página realizo la misma consulta y se muestra de manera correcta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En qué parte exactamente deseas quitar los ceros en la columna precio de venta?

Comment: Por ejemplo deseo que queden solamente 2 decimales y la parte de existencias quede sin decimales

Comment: Necesitamos ver algo de código, además ¿qué características quieres editar?

Comment: Falta información para poder darte una solución. Por ejemplo, de que forma están llegandole esos valores a la tabla, que tipo de dato son, como se muestran en la BD?, no me parece que sea un problema del DataTable.

Comment: Listo , ya edite la pregunta con información más detallada.

Answer (score 1):

Para dar formato a los números se usa `number_format()` ejemplo:

```
//Aquí te va dar con dos decimales, cambia el numero de acuerdo 
//a los decimales que necesites

     echo "<tr>";
                echo '<th>'.$row['art_Clave'].'</th>';
                echo '<th>'.$row['art_Nombre'].'</th>';
                echo '<th>'.number_format($row['art_Total'],2).'</th>'; 
                echo '<th>'.number_format($row['art_Existencia'],2).'</th>';
                echo "</tr>";
```

Y para dar formato a la tabla ya pueden usar las librerias de bootstrap [1](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap)https://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap para datatable y en la funcion especifica lo que se necesite Ejemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#table_id').DataTable({
          'bPaginate': true, //Para paginar la tabla
         });
        } );
    </script>
```